# bash: expo: command not found

Tags: bash, npm, expo

Нужна ваша помощь. Чтобы работать вместе с react-native я установил expo-cli с помощью команды `npm install --global expo cli`. expo-cli мне оно установило по такому пути: `C: \ Users \ Admin \ .npm-global \ node_modules`, а также некоторые файлы на картинке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Когда хочу создать react-native приложение в git bash получаю ошибку: `bash: expo: command not found`. У меня установлена ​​Node.js 14.18.0 LTS на диске D. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно следует добавить папку с установленной программой в системную или пользовательскую переменную path: проводник-правый клик на "мой компьютер"-свойства-переменные среды (кнопка). Выбрать переменную path и нажать изменить. Пути должны разделятся точкой с запятой к примеру 'c:/dir1/subdir;c:/dir2/;' Вставить путь к директории с установленной программой, теперь она будет доступна из cmd. Но возможно, ты не используешь cmd, следовательно следует конфигурировать твою оболочку командной строки.

Comment: Я открыл системные переменные и там у меня была переменная path. Я добавил мой путь к expo-cli C: \ Users \ Admin \ .npm-global \ node_modules \ expo-cli, но ошибка та же. Даже из командной строки не работает мне и дает ошибку: ` 'expo" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @Ronald С этой ошибкой посмотрите [здесь](https://thecoderain.blogspot.com/2019/04/windows-expo-not-recognized-internal-external-solution.html)

Comment: В твоём случае путь к экспо "C: \Users\ Admin \ .npm-global \" без пробелов. Суть в том, что программы\скрипты указаные находящиеся в папках содержащихся в path можно выполнять записав лишь имя в цмд.

Comment: @Dmitry, спасибо, спасибо, я так же все сделал, но не работает. не видит ...

Comment: перезагружал комп?

Comment: @ganz, конечно, результат тот же.

Comment: @Ronald вы уже бьетесь с этой проблемой не первый день, на enSO вам тоже не ответили. Может все снести и шаг за шагом спокойно все сделать. Отслеживая статусы ошибок и понимая, что у вас происходит?

Comment: пробуй ввести expo.cmd или полный путь к программе типа c:/dir/dir/program.exe upd: вводи expo-cli

Comment: @Dmitry, Я прошу прощения, что мучаю своим вопросом долгое время. Я не один раз переустанавливал Node вместе со всеми файлами и очисткой кэша, пробовал заменить LTS на текущую. Даже когда я устанавливал expo, у меня было куча warnings, но оно как бы установило. Когда я первый раз установил expo на ноуте, было все идеально ... Я не знаю, после этого может я какой-то файл потерял или путь поменял, что потом мне вообще не работало.

Comment: @Ronald меня то вы совершенно не беспокоите, вы себя больше мучаете. Это мое решение писать или игнорировать. Просто не плодите одинковые вопросы в дальнейшем и пытайтесь вникнуть, что же все таки происходит.